# Can I minimize tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits without reduce_mean?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I'm training my multi label model with tensorflow. The loss is calculated with `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits`. Can I just minimize the loss without `reduce_sum` or `reduce_mean` like this:

```
...
#loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=labels, logits=logits)) ## not do this
loss = tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(multi_class_labels=labels, logits=logits)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1) # do this
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
...
```

Comment: Loss is defined as sum or mean of a specific function, so you can't remove the sum/mean and expect the result to have any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use minimize() with a non-scalar Tensor. But minimize() calculates reduce_sum for a  non-scalar Tensor internally, so I recommend that you use reduce_sum for readability.